# Node - EJS - Display toastjs message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, flash-message

I'm trying to display a toast message using the library ToastrJS. The message display okay. The problem is that I'm not finding a way to pass the error message. I use connect-flash to do flash-messages, and then I wanna pass the message to the toaster.

My EJS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title><%=title%></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/nav-bar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=style%>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/aos.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/css/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.0.1/js/toastr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Joobber</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ver todas as vagas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vagas por categoria:</a></li>

          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Ainda não está cadastrado?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <% if(success.length > 0){ %>
      <script>
        toastr.success('WANNA USE THE ERROR MESSAGE VARIABLE HERE!!!!')
      </script>
    <% } %>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/aos.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    AOS.init({
      offset: 200,
      duration: 600,
      easing: 'ease-in-sine',
      delay: 100,
      });
    </script>
```

I also have connect-flash configured and used some locals variables to set the specific kind of message

```
app.use(flash());
var sessionFlash = function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
    res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
    next();

}
app.use(sessionFlash)
```

And then, my routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const indexControllers = require('../controllers/indexControllers')


router.get('/', indexControllers.HomePage)

router.get('/signup', indexControllers.Signup)

router.get('/test', (req, res)=>{
  req.flash('success', 'user succesfulyl registered')
  res.redirect('/')
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display toastr with error and message using one sentence then using toastr.info. If not, better off separating between success and error message to have clearer context. And use it like this:

```
<% if(success.length > 0){ %>
  <script>
    toastr.success(`${success[0]}`)
  </script>
<% } %>
<% if(error.length > 0){ %>
  <script>
    toastr.error(`${error[0]}`)
  </script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks! but, just for complement your answer. Your code did not work, but  just changed ``${success[0]}` to <%=success%> with the interpolation and worked. Also, thank you so much!